# How can I query two tables in one query?

Tags: sql

How do I merge/combine  this query:

```
SELECT pages.*, pages_content.title, 
    pages_content.label FROM pages, 
    pages_content WHERE
    pages.menu='top' AND pages_content.parent = 
    pages.ID order by 
    pages.sequence ASC"
```

Into this one:

```
"SELECT a.ID, a.parent, a.title, a.label, a.link, a.sequence, Deriv1.Count  FROM 
pages a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM 
pages WHERE menu='top' GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.ID = Deriv1.parent 
WHERE a.parent=" . $parent1 . " AND menu='top' order by sequence ASC"
```

The last query works but i need to replace the title and label data form another table (pages_content) as is done in the first query

How on Earth can I combine the two or fit in two? left outer joins

Comment: please, add your code between code tags

Comment: Please show the actual query, and not the code that creates it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, to make the second query

```
-- Original select clause
SELECT a.ID, a.parent, a.title, a.label, a.link, a.sequence, Deriv1.Count  
-- Add additional columns
,b.title,b.label_data
FROM pages a  
-- Add the page_content table
JOIN pages_content b on b.parent=a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM pages 
        WHERE menu='top' GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.ID = Deriv1.parent 
WHERE a.parent=" . $parent1 . " AND menu='top' 
order by sequence ASC"
```

Comment: That one gave an error as is,
But this one does work sofar ;) thanks for the effort anyway and merry x-mass
// $query = "SELECT a.ID, a.parent, (SELECT title FROM ".$_SESSION['pages_content']." WHERE parent = a.ID) as title, (SELECT label FROM ".$_SESSION['pages_content']." WHERE parent = a.ID) as label, a.link, a.sequence, Deriv1.Count  FROM ".$GLOBALS['pages']." a LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ".$GLOBALS['pages']." WHERE menu='top' GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.ID = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent1 . " AND menu='top' order by sequence ASC";

Comment: What error did you get, just glancing at it,it looks OK syntax wise.   What version of SQL are you using?